# Why did my array turn into [object object]

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
function fetchAccounts() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', "account_url", true);
    request.onload = function () {
        console.log(JSON.parse(request.responseText))
        accounts_array = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        console.log("accounts"+accounts_array)
    };
    request.send();
}
```

The first `console.log` printed out the data from my database correctly.
The second `console.log` was used to check the array. however, the output was
`accounts[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

What went wrong in between when setting `accounts_array` to the results?
I have `accounts_array` declared somewhere else.

Comment: Don't try to concatenate an object with a string. Change your `console.log` statement to: `console.log("accounts", accounts_array)`

Comment: Because you're trying effectively doing `console.log("accounts"+(accounts_array.toString()))

Comment: Nothing happened. You are merely a victim of JavaScript's automatic type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"accounts"+accounts_array` converts `accounts_array` to a **string**, and then appends it to `"accounts"`. Turning an array into a string calls `toString` on the array, which calls `join`, which goes through all the entries of the array converting them to string and joins them together with a `,` in-between. Apparently your array contains plain objects with the default `toString` method, so they convert to `"[object Object]"`. That's why you have a series of `[object Object]` with commas between them.

Here's an example:

```js
const accounts_array = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
console.log("accounts" + accounts_array);
```

If you want to see the array's contents, log it as its own thing, e.g.:

```
console.log("accounts", accounts_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This tries to *concatenate two strings* and log the resulting string to the console:

```
console.log("accounts"+accounts_array)
```

But `accounts_array` isn't a string.  It's an array of complex objects.  (Don't get hung up on the term "complex", even for very simply object.  It's just a way of saying it's something more involved than just a simple value.)  And the default string representation for an object is `"[object object]"`.

Alternatively, this logs a string to the console followed by the array or object:

```
console.log("accounts", accounts_array)
```

Which is a handy way of labeling `console.log` statements while still logging the entirety of the more complex object.

Answer (score -1):

I think do you have one array of objects of your db. To check if data is what you want, loop your data and do a console.log for each element.

I think is just the method of console.log prints your array